# Quitting emacs is very slow

Tags: debugging, quitting

Quitting my Emacs takes a really long time.

Is there a good way to track what's happening while quitting Emacs?

(So far I'm turning to git blame to figure out what changes I have made to cause this problem.)

Comment: Yes, type:  `M-x describe-variable RET kill-emacs-hook RET`

Comment: Since several buffers are often killed when quitting Emacs, also type:  `M-x describe-variable RET kill-buffer-hook RET`.

Comment: Check whether you are automatically saving something when you quit. Prime candidates are saving a desktop and saving bookmarks.

Comment: If you don't see the problem when you use `emacs -Q` (no init file) then recursively bisect your init file until you isolate the problematic part. This is quick and foolproof.

Comment: Thank you @lawlist and @Drew for your helpful comments. In fact, my problem was solved by inspecting kill-emacs-hook (It turned out that `migemo-pattern-alist-save` was causing the slow quit). @lawlist , it would be great if you could move your comment into an answer, so I can accept it as the solution. Thank you for both of you.